# Navigator.geolocation not updating a typescript property

Tags: html, knockout.js, geolocation, typescript, durandal

I am writing a location service that calls the new html5 navigator.geolocation class. However the service always returns my default values for these properties unless I change the 'maximumAge' value to '99999' but then I am worried that it will only work for a short amount of time.

Here is my locationService:

```
export class LocationService {
private static _instance: LocationService = null;
public Latitude: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(0);
public Longitude: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(2);

constructor() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.Longitude(position.coords.longitude);
        this.Latitude(position.coords.latitude);
    }, () => {
        alert('please use HTML5 enabled browser');
            // TODO: use yahoo API and postcode from DB to get location long & lat fall back for browsers not supporting this call
    }, {
            timeout: 10000,
            maximumAge: 1,
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        }
    );
}

public static GetInstance(): LocationService {
    if (LocationService._instance === null) {
        LocationService._instance = new LocationService();
    }
    return LocationService._instance;
}

private noLocation() {

}

}
```

here is how I consume it in a durandal widget:

```
import locationService = require("services/locationService");

export class testWidget{
public locationServ: locationService.LocationService = locationService.LocationService.GetInstance();
public Latitude: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(1);
public Longitude: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(3);

constructor() {
    this.Latitude.subscribe(function (newLat) {
        alert("test change : " + newLat);
    });
    this.Latitude(this.locationServ.Latitude());
    this.Longitude(this.locationServ.Longitude());
}

public activate() {
    alert("test: " + this.Latitude() + this.Longitude());
}



}

return new testWidget();
```

This code alerts 'test change : 0' and then 'test: 02' unless I change the timeout in which case it alerts real long and lat values.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated as I have pulled my hair out all day over this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The member's are called

```
public Latitude: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(1);
public Longitude: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(3);
```

*before* the constructor body :

```
this.Latitude(this.locationServ.Latitude());
this.Longitude(this.locationServ.Longitude());
```

So you effectively have :

```
public Latitude: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(1);
public Longitude: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(3);
this.Latitude(this.locationServ.Latitude());
this.Longitude(this.locationServ.Longitude());
```

And since locationServ has

```
public Latitude: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(0);
public Longitude: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(2);
```

`0` , `2` you get 0,2

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is true but I want the result from the geolaction call: position.coords.longitude & position.coords.latitude which is called in the constructor of the service (after the population of the defaults from the properties)